RTW Embedded coder generating #includes in C file instead of H file
Environment:
Matlab R2022b
Simulink model
Problem:
I was generating code from Embedded coder and generated codes have header file declaration present in the C file instead of H file. I used the same model in another computer with R2020b (after exporting to previous version), and same model generated the # includes in H file.

What are “header file declarations”? Are you talking about include statements? Those are expected in a C file. Please clarify what you are seeing by including a [mre], and please explain why it is a problem. Also, don’t forget to ask a question explicitly. It makes it easier to provide an answer without guessing at what you want to learn.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
